# Admob só precisa de um codigo XML?

Tags: java, android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o Admob precisa somente deste código ou precisa de alguma classe criada?

Comment: Paiva, tente não inserir imagem do seu código, mas sim o próprio código aqui. Isso facilita muito!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NÃO.** Você precisa fazer uma requisição para recuperar o anúncio, no qual só é possível através de uma classe. Veja um exemplo:

```
// fazendo uma requisição 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// adicionando a requisição no AdView.
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação sobre AdRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest).

Comment: Mas antes eu preciso vincular o adview com o XML que criei né?

Comment: @Paiva sim, você tem que instanciar seu xml com a classe java.